# mysql sum using left join on three tables

Tags: mysql

We have following tables...

```
users
id, username password email

user_clubs
id, user_id, club_name

sales
id, club_id, amount, admin_fees, dnt
```

We are trying to get total sum of admin_fees as outstanding for user_id(for example 5), and we tried following...

```
SELECT u.id, count(c.id), SUM(s.admin_fees) as total_admin_fees 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_clubs c ON c.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.club_id = c.id
WHERE u.id = 5
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Which is only returning results for first row, which is incorrect, Please help to resolve.

here is [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a317f/3) to test.

thanks

Comment: I don't get it. Your code does sum all admin fees for the proper club for the proper user. What's the problem ?

Comment: And your result seems correct. What are you expecting?

Comment: The query is working as expected. You're grouping rows on userID. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @all I would have to add more data to make it clear, as on real data i am getting 0 as total

Comment: sorry, I tried, but I cannot replicate the problem. Can you try to get a dataset together that produces the problem. I think there may be a conflict of data. For instance what if two users are in the same club that owes admin fees. Do they both owe the same amount, or would that amount owed be split between the two?

Comment: @amaster507 thanks for your reply, 1 user can have many clubs, and admin_fees is like commission which is paid by user to admin on per sale.

Comment: @seoppc so that explains that, now can you show at least one dataset where the result is not what is expected?

Comment: @amaster507 ok give me some time, i will put real data to sqlfiddle, thanks for your help btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for `user_id = 5` there are two club ids and with amount 2,5  so total should be **7**

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(c.id), SUM(s.admin_fees) AS total_admin_fees 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_clubs c ON c.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.club_id = c.id
WHERE u.id = 5
GROUP BY s.club_id;
```

for all users you can do this

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(c.id), SUM(s.admin_fees) AS total_admin_fees 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_clubs c ON c.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.club_id = c.id

GROUP BY u.`id`;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a317f/12)